# matlab error with LDA classification

Tags: classification, matlab

I want classify my data with LDA (Linear discriminant analysis) classifier.  My test data size is:

```
1    12   240    64
```

And my train data size is:

```
85    12   240    64
```

My label size is:

```
1 85
```

For this purpose I used classify MATLAB code like this:

```
class = classify(Test_data, Train_data, label, 'linear');
```

But it give me error:

> The length of GROUP must equal the number of rows in TRAINING.

I don't know why give me this error because as you see, my TRAINING data row number is `85`, the same as my `label(GROUP)` length.  Can some one please tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the cause of a Matlab-specific error message; it appears to be a Matlab-syntax issue rather than a statistical issue.

Comment: @ ttnphns  LDA or Linear discriminant analysis and the related Fisher's linear discriminant are methods used in statistics, pattern recognition and machine learning to find a linear combination of features which characterizes or separates two or more classes of objects or events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDA works on rows; note the documentation "training and group must have the same number of rows".

Your labels are currently specified in columns. The following will fix your error:

```
class = classify(Test_data,Train_data,label','linear');
```

Note the ' after label to transpose into rows.

Comment: thank you @Alex. it work, but now it give me another error like "SAMPLE and TRAINING must have the same number of columns."but i am sure both have same columns number, and why dose it matter if i write label' or label because i thought what matter is length of label not row or columns number.i can not  understand that.

Comment: No problem!  In general, I think you need to look more closely at the size of your variables and understand the difference between column vectors and row vectors. Row and column number *definitely* matter!

See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classify.html

    class = classify(sample,training,group)

In general, sizes should be:
size(sample) ==  (num_samples, num_variables),   
size(training) == (num_samples, num_variables),
size(training) == (num_samples, 1).

Currently your matrices are way too big (4d vs. 2d), so think  carefully about how your data structures. Good luck!

Comment: thank you @Alex.i found matlab only support 2d data so i convert all my 3d and 4d data to a 2d matrix and with your help i finally solve my problem.